# Workaround for mobile browsers unpredictable clip behavior on fixed position scrollable div?

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed position div with scrollable content, and it needs to cover the entire screen. The top 50px of the div should be hidden and transparent, but its content should scroll normally and the scrollbar should be full height.

My solution is to use clip, but if I try to clip the div with a rectangle, it renders unpredictably on mobile browsers (tested in Chrome for Android and the stock browser, and Chrome Dev Tools Device Mode). I believe it's a rendering bug, because it works perfectly on desktop.

What's a workaround to make this work as expected? See the demo below, or check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s1t1g8n9/1). Note how it works well on desktop (top 50px are transparent and content looks normal, and scrollbar covers the full body height), while on mobile the content is usually chopped off and there are other glitches.

Bonus question: Why does it render so weirdly on mobile? I'm curious to hear an explanation.

```css
#content{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  clip: rect(50px, 100vw, 100vh, 0px);
  
  // looks
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quodsi ipsam honestatem undique pertectam atque absolutam. Et quidem, inquit, vehementer errat; Nam memini etiam quae nolo, oblivisci non possum quae volo. Praeclare hoc quidem. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Nos paucis ad haec additis finem faciamus aliquando; Quod cum dixissent, ille contra. Ratio enim nostra consentit, pugnat oratio. Stulti autem malorum memoria torquentur, sapientes bona praeterita grata recordatione renovata delectant. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. </p>

<p>Habes, inquam, Cato, formam eorum, de quibus loquor, philosophorum. Ergo infelix una molestia, fellx rursus, cum is ipse anulus in praecordiis piscis inventus est? Quod, inquit, quamquam voluptatibus quibusdam est saepe iucundius, tamen expetitur propter voluptatem. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Hoc est non modo cor non habere, sed ne palatum quidem. </p>

<p>Quid est enim aliud esse versutum? Quarum ambarum rerum cum medicinam pollicetur, luxuriae licentiam pollicetur. Nam ante Aristippus, et ille melius. Istam voluptatem, inquit, Epicurus ignorat? Quasi vero, inquit, perpetua oratio rhetorum solum, non etiam philosophorum sit. Non enim quaero quid verum, sed quid cuique dicendum sit. Qui convenit? Et ille ridens: Video, inquit, quid agas; Quod cum dixissent, ille contra. Eiuro, inquit adridens, iniquum, hac quidem de re; At negat Epicurus-hoc enim vestrum lumen estquemquam, qui honeste non vivat, iucunde posse vivere. Quis est enim, in quo sit cupiditas, quin recte cupidus dici possit? </p>

<p>Sin tantum modo ad indicia veteris memoriae cognoscenda, curiosorum. Beatus autem esse in maximarum rerum timore nemo potest. Est enim tanti philosophi tamque nobilis audacter sua decreta defendere. At iam decimum annum in spelunca iacet. Cur igitur, cum de re conveniat, non malumus usitate loqui? At, si voluptas esset bonum, desideraret. Sed mehercule pergrata mihi oratio tua. Quae cum dixisset paulumque institisset, Quid est? </p>

<p>Sint modo partes vitae beatae. Quae hic rei publicae vulnera inponebat, eadem ille sanabat. Qui autem esse poteris, nisi te amor ipse ceperit? Ex quo intellegitur officium medium quiddam esse, quod neque in bonis ponatur neque in contrariis. </p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quodsi ipsam honestatem undique pertectam atque absolutam. Et quidem, inquit, vehementer errat; Nam memini etiam quae nolo, oblivisci non possum quae volo. Praeclare hoc quidem. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Nos paucis ad haec additis finem faciamus aliquando; Quod cum dixissent, ille contra. Ratio enim nostra consentit, pugnat oratio. Stulti autem malorum memoria torquentur, sapientes bona praeterita grata recordatione renovata delectant. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. </p>

<p>Habes, inquam, Cato, formam eorum, de quibus loquor, philosophorum. Ergo infelix una molestia, fellx rursus, cum is ipse anulus in praecordiis piscis inventus est? Quod, inquit, quamquam voluptatibus quibusdam est saepe iucundius, tamen expetitur propter voluptatem. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Hoc est non modo cor non habere, sed ne palatum quidem. </p>

<p>Quid est enim aliud esse versutum? Quarum ambarum rerum cum medicinam pollicetur, luxuriae licentiam pollicetur. Nam ante Aristippus, et ille melius. Istam voluptatem, inquit, Epicurus ignorat? Quasi vero, inquit, perpetua oratio rhetorum solum, non etiam philosophorum sit. Non enim quaero quid verum, sed quid cuique dicendum sit. Qui convenit? Et ille ridens: Video, inquit, quid agas; Quod cum dixissent, ille contra. Eiuro, inquit adridens, iniquum, hac quidem de re; At negat Epicurus-hoc enim vestrum lumen estquemquam, qui honeste non vivat, iucunde posse vivere. Quis est enim, in quo sit cupiditas, quin recte cupidus dici possit? </p>

<p>Sin tantum modo ad indicia veteris memoriae cognoscenda, curiosorum. Beatus autem esse in maximarum rerum timore nemo potest. Est enim tanti philosophi tamque nobilis audacter sua decreta defendere. At iam decimum annum in spelunca iacet. Cur igitur, cum de re conveniat, non malumus usitate loqui? At, si voluptas esset bonum, desideraret. Sed mehercule pergrata mihi oratio tua. Quae cum dixisset paulumque institisset, Quid est? </p>

<p>Sint modo partes vitae beatae. Quae hic rei publicae vulnera inponebat, eadem ille sanabat. Qui autem esse poteris, nisi te amor ipse ceperit? Ex quo intellegitur officium medium quiddam esse, quod neque in bonis ponatur neque in contrariis. </p>



</div>
```

Comment: Seems like removing `clip` really helps. Tbh, I've never seen `clip` before, so maybe it only works with `position: absolute;`? I don't have a good answer but seems like that's what's causing the hiccup on mobile.

Comment: I really can't understand the question

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/ also `clip` is deprecated

Comment: Ah but `clip-path` has such lousy support right now :(

Comment: @dippas, I edited the question. Perhaps it's clearer now?